# Angular7 RXJS @ngrx/effects select user on route change

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators, effects

I am trying to make the following functionality in an Angular7,  @ngrx/effects environment:

There is a user id in the URL and I would like to select a user from the users array received from the server (`/api/users` endpoint). 
I would like to make an API call with userService.getUsers and after it's finished I would like to select the user, from the users array received from the server, with the user id present in the URL.

So far I've got this, but this one does not dispatch an action for the user selection based on the URL param, it only dispatches and action for setting all the accounts.

```
  @Effect()
  loadUsers$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userActions.LOAD_USERS),
    switchMap(() => this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
      map((accounts: UserAccount[]) => new LoadUsersSuccessAction(accounts),
      catchError(() => of(new LoadUsersFailAction()))
    ))
  ));
```

How could I wait for a URL param change and dispatch 2 actions with

a) the accounts were loaded (LoadUsersSuccessAction) and

b) based on the URL param (like `/users/{id}`) select a user from the users received from the server (SelectUserAction)?

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure I have to use `combineLatest` operator, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

To whom may it concern I could implement the behaviour by the following expression:

```
  @Effect()
  loadAccounts$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(partnerActions.LOAD_ACCOUNTS),
    switchMap(() =>
      combineLatest(this.partnerService.getAccounts(), of(this.route.firstChild),
        (accounts: UserAccount[], url) => {
          const userId = url.snapshot.params.userId;
          const user = accounts.find(acc => +acc.id === +userId);
          return {
            accounts,
            user
          };
        }
      ).pipe(
        switchMap(({accounts, user}) => [new LoadAccountsSuccessAction(accounts), new SelectAccountAction(user)]),
        catchError(() => of(new LoadAccountsFailAction()))
      )
    ));
```